# How do I correct the python code below so that the labels are displaying correctly?

Tags: python-3.x, axis, linegraph

I'm having problems with the following code snippet whereby the labels on the x-axis are not displaying correctly (please see image at end of post).

```
ax = axs[i]
ax.plot(data.X_displacement, data.X_stiffness_force, color='steelblue', label='X_stiffness_forces')
ax.plot(data.Y_displacement, data.Y_stiffness_force, color='orange', label='Y_stiffness_forces')
ax.plot(data.Z_displacement, data.Z_stiffness_force, color='purple', label='Z_stiffness_forces')
plt.ylabel('Stiffness force, in N')
plt.xlabel('Displacement, in m')
#plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor =(0.75, 0.25))
plt.xticks([-0.025, -0.020, -0.015, -0.010, -0.005,  0, 0.005, 0.010, 0.015, 0.020, 0.025])
plt.xlim(-0.025,0.025)
plt.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=90)
plt.yticks([-0.006, -0.005, -0.004, -0.003, -0.002, -0.001, 0, 0.001, 0.002, 0.003, 0.004, 0.005, 0.006])
plt.ylim(-0.006,0.006)
```

The labels should be every 0.005, rotated at 90 degrees, between the range of -0.025 and 0.025

I have tried commenting out plt.xlim

There is no change to the plot

I have tried commenting out `plt.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=90)`

There is no change to the plot

[image: incorrect x-axis labels]

Comment: Please check the second parameter for `xticks` here: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html  (**labels
array-like, optional**  The labels to place at the given ticks locations. This argument can only be passed if ticks is passed as well.)

Comment: I've read through the link but find it difficult to understand.  Can you elaborate please?

Comment: Try to change the line with xticks to:  `plt.xticks([-0.025, -0.020, -0.015, -0.010, -0.005,  0, 0.005, 0.010, 0.015, 0.020, 0.025], [-0.025, -0.020, -0.015, -0.010, -0.005,  0, 0.005, 0.010, 0.015, 0.020, 0.025])`  (Specifying the array with ticks two times.).  This second parameters has  "The labels to place at the given ticks locations"

Comment: hmm, doesn't seem to work...  Thank you though

Comment: Sorry I could not test myself, I am missing data in your question....